# SQL: How to get distinct value combined from row results

Tags: sql

I hope I can explain this properly.
This is what the result of the table looks like

[image]

Content_IDs of 4,5,6 are NEWS.  As long as there is one boolean of true the column IsContentUpdated for NEWS, I'd like the distinct NEWS boolean to be true otherwise false.

Ultimately what I'd just want to get is

[image]

I tried with a temp table with a count of IsContentUpdated but it didn't work very well. 
I'm kind of convinced I shouldn't need a temp table but am having a brain cramp trying to think what I can do here.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Could you add a bit larger picture ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure I understand well, but if what you wanna get is what you show, it should be

```
SELECT Page_ID, MAX(CAST(IsContentUpdated AS INT))
FROM Table
GROUP BY Page_ID
```

Comment: +1 - This is what I came up with.  SQL-Server didn't like `MAX()` on a `BIT` column, so I had to `CAST( AS INT)` inside the `MAX()`

Comment: @AdamWenger oh, good point on MAX on BIT operand ! Edited for the future ;)

Comment: Holy smokes! That is brilliant.  I thought I needed to do something complex and thought that querying against a temp table would be easier.  This is even better. 
THanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a distinct list of the `Page_ID`s and whether or not any of them have a `IsContentUpdated = 1`:

```
select distinct Page_ID, max(IsContentUpdated)
from myTable
group by Page_ID
```